# Relation to the same model, prism

Tags: prisma

I am trying to make a relationship with the same model. I use prisma with MongoDB, the problem is that prisma does not allow making a relationship to the same model, making a `prisma format` should fix the problem but it does not. The documentation doesn't have anything like it to guide me, so I just don't know what to do. I tried ChatGPT but it gives me wrong answers. I need each product model to have a `relatedProducts` property that references the same model. I'm just stuck, please help.
[image]

[image]
[image]